# Use Wordpress for static WebSite

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a static website and use wordpress only to "compose" the website. I want to create a template that only use the same header and footer and change the content of the page (home, contact ecc dcc). My site is not a blog or any other type of site that needs CMS I only want to use Wordpress to have only one header and footer and don' t want to change it in all pages when I need some customization to it. I hope I was clear enough! Thanks!

Comment: What server side language are you using?  If you aren't going to be entering the content into wordpress I wouldn't bother using it.  Stick to server side includes for your header and footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Settings | Reading** admin page, choose a static page for your front page display. Build your site out using Pages instead of Posts.  Each Page will inherit your site's standard header and footer.  Create your Main Menu from the **Appearance | Menu** admin page to hook together your Pages.  Use widgets and standard HTML links as needed.  Then dress up your site with one of the many available themes.

Comment: I don't understand very well. The front page is only the home of my site? I tried to create a index.php importing only the header.php and footer.php and in the middle use my HTML code and works great but what about other page? How can I link all other page in may navigation? Thanks!

Comment: Correct.  You can build the rest of your site out using Pages instead of Posts and hook them together with the menu, widgets and standard HTML links.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it leaves a (probably) unpatched and non-updated WordPress install floating around with no security or core updates applied. This may be a valid approach on wordpress.com or someplace else that provides WP hosting and updates everything behind the scenes as part of hosting, but should not be used by anyone using the "famous 5-minute installation."

Answer (score 5):

You can create a site in WordPress (or any other CMS) on your own local computer, then save a copy using an offline browser such as [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). Then upload the HTTrack saved HTML to your webhost.

This will make your site faster, as there will be no need to execute PHP on page requests, and the webserver will use its default caching headers. (Also, you get the option of using a cheaper hosting without support for PHP and MySQL.)

Any time you change the site, you'll need to edit the live WordPress version, save it again, and reupload the files.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm dev of the [WP Static HTML Output](https://wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin) project.

It's been around for a few years and still has 5k+ active installs, but jazzing it up with some more features now and its whole purpose is to allow you to use WordPress for your site development and export to a static HTML version for speed, security and portability.

For the OP, the basic FTP publishing option may be of use. For more advanced cases, there are services like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) which can auto build/deploy your static site from a Git branch.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the table on this one but it seems that Wordpress is totally overkill for a static site. Wordpress pages can be cached with cache plugins but when any Wordpress site loads there are a number of scripts and custom php functions that run each time a page loads.

Why not just build a flat file website and simply include your header and footer with PHP? Far quicker to set up and based on your question it seems that this is simply what you need.

Added to this, you won't have an admin area for your site or a database, just the files on the server - surely this makes your site less hackable too. An added bonus is a really easy site to version control with Git or SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If there's someone else out there wanting to use a static site generator over Wordpress, here's a script called WP Static which does just this: http://mossiso.com/code/make-wordpress-static

Answer (score 0):

Another great solution to this problem is to use a specific software that is created exactly to do that. For Mac, for example, there's a software called [Hammer](http://hammerformac.com) that "compile" your site every time you save and includes your header and footer to the page. Is really useful.